# How to make a post request with angular 5

Tags: angular

i want to make a post resquest using angular 5, but it gives me an error : here is the code :

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
//Grab everything with import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { User } from '../iterface';

import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
   })
};

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

_baseUrl: string = '';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this._baseUrl = "http://sso-app-bonita.qualif.dauphine.fr:8080/bonita/";
}

addUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>(this._baseUrl, '/API/identity/user', httpOptions)
        .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('addHero', user))
        );
}


private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
        console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
        // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
        // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
        console.error(
            `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
            `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an ErrorObservable with a user-facing error message
    return new ErrorObservable(
        'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
};

}
```

component.ts

```
heroes :[];

createUser() {
  this.dataService.addUser(this.user2)
  .subscribe(hero => this.heroes.push(hero));
}
```

it gives me an error :

> TypeError: this.selector is not a function
>   Stack trace:
>   CatchSubscriber.prototype.error@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/catchError.js:108:26

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try using this in your service.ts

```
import {Headers} from 'angular2/http';
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append(headerName, value);

addUser(user : User){
    return this.http.post(this._baseUrl + '/API/identity/user',user,{ headers: headers}).map((response: Response) =>{
    console.log (response.json());
    })
}
```

here you need to send user interface to HTTP post. and map your response.

in ts file

```
createUser(){

 this.dataService.addUser(this.user2).subscribe(data => {alert("Succesfully Added Product details")},Error => {alert("failed while adding product details")})
}
```

Comment: that works , but how can send httpOptions in the header ?

Comment: thanks but actually, i kept the code like that this.http.post(this._baseUrl + 'loginservice',httpOptions) ..., i passed what i want in the httpOptions, but i sent the request to the server api, i got this message : Cross-Origin Request blocking: Same Origin policy does not allow to check the remote resource located on http://sso********************:8080/api/loginservice . Reason: The CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is missing.

Comment: This a problem with the CORS configuration on the server. It is not clear what server are you using.. which server language you are using?

Comment: java , i'm just consuming the the app's APIs, what is the solution please?

Comment: add this to your spring controller @CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000"})

Comment: i'm just consuming the apis, the app is made by another company

Comment: yes, brother but if you are adding headers and they have not allowed cross allow origin to your localhost you cannot access api's data.this is a general problem and you can get any solution on this on StackOverflow and google too. if this helped you don't forget to upvote so this can be helpful to others. any discussion we can continue to chat. happy coding.

Answer (score 9):

Let's give this a try...

```js
//FileName: login.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpParams, HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    private _loginUrl = 'http://1.2.3.4/signin'; //the api url where we need to make a call
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {} //this initialized the HttpClient which we use to do a post or get call

    //setting body of the parameters to send via post 
    private body = new HttpParams()
    .set('username', 'onetap')
    .set('password', '123456');

    checkLogin(){
         return this._http.post(this._loginUrl,
            this.body.toString(),
            {
              headers: new HttpHeaders()
                .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
            }
          )
        .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError) // then handle the error
       );
    }
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }
}
```

Let me explain this now... 
First things first... go and refer this [link](https://angular.io/guide/http) , which is the basic guide with live example on how setup httpclient and use it.

In this code lets start with **imports**:
**Injectable**: A decorator which will help you inject this service into any component you need. Just import then set it in @Component providers then create instance of it in constructor and use it using **this**.

**HttpParams**: Set the parameter or data to send for 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

**HttpClient**: This is the module using which we implement the get, post put methods.

**throwError, catchError, retry**: This could be your homework to research on.

checkLogin() implements the post method. Using HttpParams we create the body instance and pass it to checkLogin.
Post request will take 3 parametes. 1. Url, 2. Data or body to send, 3. Optional headers.

Now we call this checkLogin from our components onSubmit method given below

```js
    onSubmit() {
        this.loginService.checkLogin()
        .subscribe(resp => {
            this.user = {
                username: resp['username'],
                email: resp['email'],
                password: resp['password']
            };
            console.log(this.user);//Check if we are getting data from server
        });
                

    }
```

After all this is done. If you are getting a CORS issue which you might get if you are on local host or a different server. Use the code below

**This is at the server end code**

do

```
npm install cors --save
```

and just add these lines in your main file where your request is going.

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
let app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

Comment: Is this solution an improvement on any of the other answers? How? It would be really helpful if you could edit your answer and explain how it solves the OP's question and how it improves other answers. Thanks!

Comment: @jayelston I am updating it with a perfect working code!

Answer (score 4):

you are missing the data you want to post it should be like this eg:-

```
this.http.post("https://reqres.in/api/users/2'",
    {
      "name": "morpheus",
      "job": "leader"
    })
    .subscribe(
        (val) => {
            console.log("POST call successful value returned in body", 
                        val);
        },
        response => {
            console.log("POST call in error", response);
        },
        () => {
            console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
        });
}
```

**In your case** `this.http.post<User>(this._baseUrl+'/API/identity/user', <yourdata> httpOptions)`

also you might want to take a look at rxjs imports

```
import { catchError, map } from "rxjs/operators";
```

Comment: @Newme its just a example in your case you have not passed the data you want to post you have passed three parameters to the post the link but no data check the in your case in the answer. did you add the rxjs imports

Comment: thaks but i changed the link into this.http.post<User>(this._baseUrl+'API/identity/user', user , httpOptions) but i got the same error

Comment: its already added import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: if you look at the code you have added it twice one up top and other at bottom

Comment: i kept just import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators'; but the same error

Comment: you might want to reproduce this in stackblitz as this should work

Comment: @Newme i cannot help you if you dnt help us you need to reproduce this for me to try

Comment: i posted all i have, the proble is here :catchError(this.handleError('addHero', user))

Answer (score 2):

It's Really Very Simple, follow as I have jotted down.

//Import Headers

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

//Create Headers

```
const ParseHeaders = {
 headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type'  : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 })
};
```

//Create Post request

```
let _URL = "www.example.com/postdata";
let FormData = "FormData1="+Data1+"&FormData2"+Data2
this.httpClient.post(_URL,FormData,ParseHeaders).subscribe((res) => {
 console.log(res);
});
```

While Receiving in server side,
if it's PHP then Use $_POST['FormData1'];
This Really works.

Answer (score 0):

At first create a component service:

```
ng g s <<name of component service>>
```

Then import the headers of httpClient:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

At second into .ts component service inject the httpClient object into the constructor:

```
constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
```

Stay in component service and create a function that it will get your information into the normal component:

```js
 public saveUser(data)
       {
        const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json',
           // 'Authorization': this.jwt
          })
        };

        return this.http.post(this._baseUrl+'/API/identity/user',data,httpOptions);
       }
```

Into the normal component just add this it will be work fine:

```js
 constructor(private user:NameofComponentService) { }
     this.user.saveUser(this.liste).subscribe(data=>{  
    //console.log(data);

  },err=>{
    console.log(err.error.message);
  })
```