# In angular using HttpClient i am unable to get the json data. When i submit the form and handle it at onSubmit() func it shows undefined on console

Tags: angular

I am building a simple login page in Angular. When the user hits submit button i currently wanted to get the login info as a json from a local file(**assets/login.json**).

I followed this [link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ooqemvjyqkb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fconfig%2Fconfig.component.ts) and tired to copy it with all the alternate ways shown but with no success also used this [link](https://angular.io/guide/http). But with no success.

I am attaching 2 main files where the logic stays. Could you help me with this?

*Coding in Angular 5

File Name: login.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ILoginDetails, LoginService } from './login.service';


import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, EmailValidator} from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'login-app' ,
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    providers: [LoginService]
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    login_details: ILoginDetails;
    dummy: any = null;
    login: FormGroup;
    result: any = null;
    errorMessage: string;
    emailPattern: any = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    constructor(private loginService: LoginService ,private frmBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.login = this.frmBuilder.group({
            email:["", [Validators.required]],
            password: ["", [Validators.required]]
        });
    }
    
    get email() { return this.login.get('email'); }
    get password() { return this.login.get('password'); }
    isSubmitted: boolean = false;

    // constructor( private loginService: LoginService ){ }
    // title = 'Login';
    onSubmit() {
        if ( !this.login.valid ) {
            return;
        }
        // Code to send to the network to validate
        this.loginService.checkLogin();
        .subscribe((data: ILoginDetails) => this.login_details = { ...data });
            console.log(this.login_details);
    }
    reset() {
        this.isSubmitted = false;
        this.login.reset();
    }
}
```

---

File Name: login.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
// import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface ILoginDetails {
    username: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    private _loginUrl = 'assets/login.json';
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

    checkLogin() {
        return this._http.get<ILoginDetails>(this._loginUrl)
        .pipe(
        retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
        catchError(this.handleError) // then handle the error
       );
    }
   
  // Prints for errors
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Subscribe is asynchronous.

Comment: The `console.log` is outside of the subscribe callback. You will have to move it within the callback if you want to log the value

Comment: @3rdi, you have an innecesary (and fatal) ";", and you need pass to the function the password and the email (I supouse). this.loginService.checkLogin(this.email,this.password).subscribe(...)

Answer (score 2):

```
        this.loginService.checkLogin()
        .subscribe((data: ILoginDetails) => {this.login_details = {
           ...data 
         };
         console.log(this.login_details); // here will print
        //here add more logic hangling your check - its the callback
       });
```

Because http client executes in async fasion, you provide callback which is a block of code that will be executed later in future just when http request will be completed.

By the time you reach your console.log() request is not completed (barely started) thus there is no data yet. Put your handling code in callback function.

Welcome to the world of asynchronicity

Comment: Don't forget you have to delete that semi-colon on line 1 to chain the subscribe method to the service method call

Comment: Failed to compile.
ERROR in src/app/access/login/login.component.ts(55,70): error TS1005: ')' expected.
src/app/access/login/login.component.ts(57,9): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
src/app/access/login/login.component.ts(66,9): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

Comment: You need to add a couple of curly brackets: one `{` immediately after the `=>`, and one `}` immediately before the last `)` of that snippet

Comment: The code which i wrote was perfectly engineered from this link at "https://stackblitz.com/angular/ooqemvjyqkb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fconfig%2Fconfig.component.ts" from the file config.component.ts and the func name is showConfig(). Just instead of "this.config" i have used my own instance of interface name "this.login_details"

Comment: @3rdi well you obviously your code is different then that you provided and not only by 1 line but by misplacing console.log.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9rdh13 check comments. Check config component code and comments. Maybe you will see the difference

Answer (score 0):

**First Things First:** In actual network call for Login you will have to send a **POST** request!
So do check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50298117/9470457) for that! and in a get call also subscribe method is important since its an async call!.

The code that will work 100% without any issue is

```
// FileName: login.service.ts
// Inside checkLogin() remove the ILoginDetails interface. the code should look like this... 

checkLogin() {
        return this._http.get(this._loginUrl)
        .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError) // then handle the error
       );
    }
```

Now in the file "login.component.ts" change the onSubmit() method with this code...

```
onSubmit() {
        if ( !this.login.valid ) {
            return;
        }
        // Code to send to the network to validate
        this.loginService.checkLogin();
        .subscribe(data => {  
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
```

***This is 100% working code, i have tested, verified and using it!**

---

The below method only works if you have a local json file.
If you **want to experiment** the below code will work too but only for files on the same server eg: "assets/login.json" file!

Just follow this steps

File Name: login.component.ts 
I got rid of the subscribe and created a variable dummy with type any then used it as given below!

```js
    onSubmit() {
        if ( !this.login.valid ) {
            return;
        }
        // this method will check for login
        this.dummy = this.loginService.checkLogin();
        // this.loginService.checkLogin()
        // .subscribe(
        //     (data: ILoginDetails) => this.login_details = { ...data });

            this.dummy.forEach(element => {
                if (element.email == this.email.value && element.password == this.password.value) {
                    this.result = "Acccess Granted";
                    return;
                }
                this.result = "Access Denied";
            }
        );
       
    }
```

.::: Any suggestions and new approaches are always welcomed and supported :::.