# Sending an object from Angular8 to Spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, web-development-server

I'm pretty new to Web Development and I admit that following several guides online I'm still a little confused about some basic concepts.
I have a **Angular8** form that works pretty fine: I insert data and click on "Submit".

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.model);
    this.submitted = true;
  }
```

And prints in the console the data of the form (I followed [this official guide](https://angular.io/guide/forms) for reference).

Here's the content of my `search-message.ts` (the class of `model`):

```
export class SearchMessage {

  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public inputText: string,
    public targetSite: string,
    public searchLimit: number,
    public details: boolean
  ) { }
}
```

Now I'm trying to write a **Spring Boot** application that will receive the `model` object and I will simply print in output the same data. No database should be involved in this procedure (and that's why I'm confused: all guides I find online are about connecting a db on a server to the view in Angular). How should I do this?

Comment: Hi, can you add the model class you're using in Angular?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @A.Wolf .  I just added it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Boot you have to define a controller class, which exposes an endpoint that you'll call from your Angular app.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/path")
public CustomController {
    @PostMapping("message")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addModel(@RequestBody SearchMessage message) {

        // do what you need with the element (ex. write to a db, print data..)
        System.out.println("Data received: " + message.toString());

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();

    }
}
```

Where SearchMessage should be something like this:

```
class SearchMessage {
    private int id; 
    private String inputText;
    private String targetSite;
    private int searchLimit;
    private boolean details;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And, assuming the backend application is running on port `8081`, you can do a post to an endpoint like this:

```
http://localhost:8081/your-app-context-path/path/message
```

where the body has to be compatible with the `SearchMessage` class that you define in the method parameter `message`.

Note that you can define the application's context path adding this property in the `application.properties` file:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/myCoolApp
```

---

You can find a complete working example in this [Spring example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). See also [this more complete article](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/).
Let me know if you need more details or explanations.

Comment: Thanks again. What do you mean when you say «where the body has to be compatible with the `SearchMessage` class» ?

Comment: Your welcome! Only that the `SearchMessage` class of the backend must have fields that are compatible with the fields of the `SearchMessage` class of the frontend, i.e. a number field should become a integer or float field in the backend and has to have the same name. Obvious thing, but in case they have different types or names the marshalling of what you pass from the frontend to the object in the backend will fail.

Comment: I added also the `SearchMessage` class.

Comment: If the answer helped you to resolve your problem, consider to accept it :)

Comment: I almost managed to solve the issue. Anyway your answer was really helpful so I'll accept it anyway :) I just have a couple more (maybe trivial) questions: so I have to run the two applications at the same time on two different ports, am I right? And how would be the POST in Angular?

Comment: Yes, exactly! For example you can run the Angular application on port 8080 and the Spring Boot application on port 8081.

Comment: For POST request see for example [this article](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/11/21/angular-http-post-request-examples) or for example [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48580502/2993413) or [the Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request)

Comment: For a more detailed response, consider to ask another question with a reference to this question (to avoid to repeat all what you already wrote here) and, If you want, add the link here as a comment.

Comment: I tried to implement a GET first just to learn :) . Here's the link to the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60024146/get-request-angularspring-not-working-why