# GET request Angular+Spring not working. Why?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, http, get

I'm trying to implement a simple **GET request** to send an Object of type `SearchMessage` from my **Spring Boot** server to my **Angular** client application. I run my server application and check if the relative JSON is correctly viewed on `localhost:8080/greeting` and it works.
Here's what I see:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "inputText": "Hello, World!",
  "targetSite": "Amazon",
  "searchLimit": 10,
  "numberOfProxies": 10,
  "details": false
}
```

I then run my client accessing to the component (`http://localhost:4200/data`) that is supposed to print in the log the content of that JSON, but instead I get in the console the following error. What am I doing wrong?

> ERROR
>
> > Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error",
> >     url: "localhost:8080/greeting", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse",
> >     message: "Http failure response for localhost:8080/greeting: 0 Unknown
> >     Error", error: error } core.js:6014:19

## Spring application

Content of `SearchMessage.java`:

```
@Entity
public class SearchMessage {

    private long id;
    private String inputText;
    private String targetSite;
    private int searchLimit;
    private int numberOfProxies;
    private boolean details;

    // Getters, setters and constructors...
}
```

Content of `GreetingController.java`:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public SearchMessage greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new SearchMessage(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name), "Amazon", 10, 10, false);
    }
}
```

Raw data displayed at `localhost:8080/greeting`:

```
{"id":3,"inputText":"Hello, World!","targetSite":"Amazon","searchLimit":10,"numberOfProxies":10,"details":false}
```

## Angular application

Content of my `http.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getGreeting() {
    return this.http.get('localhost:8080/greeting');
  }
}
```

Content of `data.component.ts`:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpService} from '../http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data',
  templateUrl: './data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data.component.scss']
})

export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  greeting: Object;

  constructor(private _http: HttpService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._http.getGreeting().subscribe(data => {
      this.greeting = data;
      console.log(this.greeting);
    });
  }
}
```

Content of `search-message.ts`:

```
export class SearchMessage {

  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public inputText: string,
    public targetSite: string,
    public searchLimit: number,
    public numberOfProxies: number,
    public details: boolean
  ) { }
}
```

Comment: Hi again :) Do you have also some log in the backend application? As @Ahmed said, you'll have to add CrossOrigin support, but I would do it at application level, not controller level.

Comment: And the error doesn't seems to me a problem of CORS.

Comment: Yes! I implemented logging in. Maybe that's the problem. I already tried with CrossOrigin and nothing changes... I'll try to remove the login and see if it works

Comment: I mean do you have something like log.debug("Backend receives data..")? Does the  backend receives the call of the frontend?

Comment: Anyway, let's start without the login to understand if the call works from FE to BE and back to FE :)

Comment: When you say  _then run my client accessing to the component (http://localhost:4200/data)_ you mean that accessing this URL the `DataComponent` is loaded so it's called the backend api from the service? Can you add also the routing file, please? The most important thing is to understand what the backend application receives.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller class add:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
```

above the @RestController annotation to make your spring boot app and angular app connect with each other. 
This is a sample controller class hope it helps.

```
     @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
     @RestController

     public class StudentsController{

    @Autowired
    StudentRepo repo;

    //insert
   @PostMapping("/students")
   public Students insert(@Valid @RequestBody Students students){
    return repo.save(students);
    }
   //list of students   
   @GetMapping("/students")
   public List<Students> index(){
   return repo.findAll();
   }}
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow CORS Origin support to your backend application you have to create a Configuration class which add Cors origin and allow to your frontend application to be able to call APIs exposed by your Spring Boot application:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
    }
}
```

You can find an example [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework).

---

I'm not sure that the problem is related to CORS, but for sure you have to add it.