# how to get json object from a webservice

Tags: python, json, angular, flask

i have the below posted json response.as shown below in json section, the `parameters`object is emitted in this line (this is an angular application)

```
    this._FromInsToSiteDataService.emitOnSubmitButtonClikedBroadcast(parameters)
```

and it is received in

```
this.subscriptionBroadcastEmitterOnSubmitButtonClicked = this._FromInsecticidesToSiteMapDataService.getBroascastEmitterOnSubmitButtonClicked().subscribe((response:Object)=>{
        response['siteGeometry'] = this.selectedSite.geometry
        console.log("response: ", response)
        this.sSProvider.startWebServiceFor(response)
    });
```

in the latter code i want to pass the response which is in json format to the webservice and receive it as show in the `websrvice`postedbelow`

when i run the code, i expected to see the contents of the json object which is

```
{
  "dist1": d1,
  "dist2": d2,
  "date1": date1,
  "date2": date2,
  "ingredient": activeIngredient
}
```

but i get `NONE`

please let me know how can i correctly get a json object from a webservice

**json**

```
 private submit() {
  let parameters = {
  "dist1": d1,
  "dist2": d2,
  "date1": date1,
  "date2": date2,
  "ingredient": activeIngredient
}
    
this._FromInsToSiteDataService.emitOnSubmitButtonClikedBroadcast(parameters)
```

**receiving the json object**

```
this.subscriptionBroadcastEmitterOnSubmitButtonClicked = this._FromInsecticidesToSiteMapDataService.getBroascastEmitterOnSubmitButtonClicked().subscribe((response:Object)=>{
        response['siteGeometry'] = this.selectedSite.geometry
        console.log("response: ", response)
        this.sSProvider.startWebServiceFor(response)
    });
```

**webservice**:

```
@app.route("/insSpecifications/<parameters>", methods=['GET'] )
def insSpecifications(parameters):
    # print(request.json())
    print(request.get_json())//returns NONE

    return "OK"
```

Comment: @Chillie the    this.sSProvider.startWebServiceFor(response)
starts the webservice

Comment: You may want to modify your tags with appropriate ones to get the correct people to look at the question, as this question is lesser a flask, python question and more of JS

Comment: Have you tested the Flask route from postman and did it print the json? Note that if you don't set the `content-type` to `application/json` in the header, `get_json()` returns null and also you are making a GET request, `get_json()` reads the body of a `post` or `put` request

Comment: @shoaib30 would you please provide an example in code?how can i set the content-type??

Comment: I will drop it as an answer

Comment: @shoaib30 ok..fine

Answer (score 0):

**Intro**
There are two parts to your question -

1. Making a request from JS
2. Creating a Flask API to handle the request

Both these have extensively answered on SO hence I will only summarize it here, please follow the links for more information

### **Answer**

**REST Method:**
When sending JSON data from the front end to the backend, you need to make a `POST` request or `PUT` depending on the need. Please read up on `REST API` concepts to understand the methods and purposes.
https://www.w3schools.in/restful-web-services/rest-methods/

**Making a request**
Depending on which library you use in the front end, the request might look different, but essentially you need to send a request with `JSON` in the body and `HEADERS` set appropriately i.e. `Content-Type: application/json`

Using `FETCH` this can be achieved by (auto-generated from postman)

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "username": "Sample1",
  "email": "test2@test.com"
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("localhost:5000/sample", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

But most libraries would have wrappers around this, please look into making a `POST` request for your respective JS library

**Creating Flask API**
Finally, you need a Flask API to consume this request. Assuming it's a `POST` request. You need to create a route with method as `POST` and get the JSON data using `get_json()` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20001283/5236575

So once the `HEADERS` are correctly set and a post request is made, your code should work fine by changing `GET` to `POST`

*Note: The `parameters` field is captured correctly hence I'm leaving it as is, but that is not where your JSON body comes from*

```
@app.route("/insSpecifications/<parameters>", methods=['POST'] )
def insSpecifications(parameters):
    # print(request.json())
    print(request.get_json())
    return "OK"
```

**Testing**
You can test your API using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or any other API testing tool to see how the API behaves and validate if the issue you have is in the API or in the front-end code.

Comment: i changed the GET method to POST and i get the following:
INFO:werkzeug: - - [02/Aug/2021 10:05:50] "OPTIONS /insecticidesSpecifications/[object%20Object] HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug: - - [02/Aug/2021 10:05:50] "GET /insecticidesSpecifications/[object%20Object] HTTP/1.1" 405 -

Comment: what is [object%20Object]??

Comment: You are passing the JSON object from the JS code as an object in the URL, Hence you see `[object: Object]`  as the URL param. You need to send the JSON in the body of the request not in the URL

Comment: i am sending from angular not from js. please let me know how to access [object object]

Comment: Angular at the end of the day is JS running on the browser. Please look into how to make POST Request from angular - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61742826/5236575

Comment: accessing `[object Object]` isn't the problem you need to solve. If you send it correctly it wont come as '[`object Object]`